# Executing JS in TWebBrowser

Tags: javascript, delphi, twebbrowser

I take http://www.foxbase.ru/delphi/javascript-na-delphi.htm worked example and trying to execute my own js code. Some corrections and its simly like this : http://shadow-core.com/ShadowJS.pas

Firstly , i dont know where is problem... Cuz , in source code in example, we simply use:

```
  js:=TDelphiJS.Create;
  js.LoadFromURL('http://vbulletin_forum.ru/clientscript/vbulletin_md5.js?v=371');
  js.DeclareVariable('mypassword');
  js.DeclareVariable('');
  js.DeclareVariable('');
  js.DeclareVariable('');
  js.Execute('md5hash');
  ShowMessage(js.GetVariable(2));
  js.free;
```

I use in my unit smth like this :

```
js:=TShadowJS.Create;
 js.LoadFromURL('http://shadow-core.com/dev/col/test.php');
 js.Execute('R()');
 Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add (js.GetVariable('TS016c63b6_id'));
 Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add (js.GetVariable('TS016c63b6_cr'));
 Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add (js.GetVariable('TS016c63b6_76'));
 Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add (js.GetVariable('TS016c63b6_86'));
 Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add (js.GetVariable('TS016c63b6_md'));
```

And my js code are not executing , only default values like this:

```
0
0
1
```

By the way , if i make event on another button

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add (js.GetVariable('TS016c63b6_id'));
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add (js.GetVariable('TS016c63b6_cr'));
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add (js.GetVariable('TS016c63b6_76'));
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add (js.GetVariable('TS016c63b6_86'));
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add (js.GetVariable('TS016c63b6_md'));
end;
```

i got result that i need.:

```
ada4857db7445f789aaacaccdfe69aa6:knjn:W0AR1OiN:287517631
w0b5cc99da3d7a58590359w39b2000w1546f47b90000w3d7a58590359f69ee455fa1a72039b20
9f5172f23c74w78bc586fd3109c321
1
```

Thats question , how to make twebbrowser executing and returning values that i need momentaly , without form's events?

Comment: Yes, i loaded some other scripts , and it works . But my script works in another way...

Comment: OilFlame, you need to fix the question.a) don't link external resources, but include all the relevant portions directly in your question.

Comment: Also the code at link http://shadow-core.com/dev/col/test.php seems malicious to me...

Comment: Its something like a defence , obfuscated ... need to eval it..

Comment: Anyway, try replacing your Sleep() call with Application.ProcessMessages and see if it helps...

Comment: And how to make in a thread this thing ?